# Parse date to cron format in javscript

Tags: javascript, cron

I have a UI that the user choose the following:

days in weeks [array]

hours , minutes, and AM/PM

for example:

Sunday, Monday , in 01:00:AM

How can I parse this data to a cron format

the Ui include checkboxes for the days and hours/minutes select box for the  Time

also - how can I do the opposite
From cron to UI data:

for example my cron

```
0 2 2 ? * SUN,MON *
At 02:02:00am, on every Sunday and Monday, every month
``
```

Comment: I suggest using a library to do this for you. It's going to be much easier.

Comment: @VLAZ which one ?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation - I've not used any myself but it's bound to be easier than trying to re-create this. Cron syntax isn't *hard*, the problem is the human language. Freely converting between the two is not a trivial task.